# Conducting paired t-test without the raw data

Tags: r, statistics, t.test

In R, I would like to conduct a paired sample t-test for two samples. I don't have the raw data. I only have three information: 1) means for both groups,  2) their variation in 95% confidence interval   3) Their N's. here is the data :

```
mean1 <- 0.5012997


  mean2 <- 0.5115595
  
  
  ci_upper1 <- 0.5141452
  ci_lower1 <- 0.48845425
  ci_upper2 <- 0.5205948
  ci_lower2 <- 0.50252432
  n1 <- 50
  n2 <- 50
```

How can I do a  paired sample t.test with this information?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer your question. Note that this is more a statistics question than a programming question, so you will have better luck asking on https://stats.stackexchange.com.

**The short answer**: you need one more piece of information, the covariance or correlation between the two samples. Without it, you can not calculate a paired *t*-Test from only group means with confidence intervals and *n*. Here is the explanation:

First of all, the formula for the *t* statistic of two paired samples is this:

[image: formula]

where *D* are the differences between the two measurements of each person. The upper part, mean of *D* (denoted with a bar above), is easy to get by. It is `mean1 - mean2`.
The hard part is to get *SD*, which is the standard deviation of the differences between measurements of each person.

It is possible to reverse engineer the standard deviations of both sample 1 (let's call it `x`) and sample 2 (`y`) out of the given confidence intervals. So we can get our hands on `sd(x)` and `sd(y)`. (See below for how to do this)

But we actually need *SD*, which is `sd(x - y)`. [This answer on the stats forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283752/standard-deviation-of-the-difference-scores-is-%e2%88%9a2-times-as-large-as-standard) tells us how `sd(x - y)` and `sd(x)` and `sd(y)` are related:

[image: formula2]

Where `cov(x, y)` is the covariance between `x` and `y`. If you happen to have this missing piece of information, you could calculate *SD* and *t* and do the test. If you don't have tho covariance or something like the correlation which contains the covariance, you can not calculate the paired t-test.

---

FYI: How to reverse engineer the confidence intervals

First: I assume these are confidence intervals which are estimating population variance with sample variance, which is pretty standard, and therefore use the *t*-distribution. Then the formula looks like this:

`ci_upper1 = mean1 + qt(.975, df = n1 - 1) * sd1 / sqrt(n1)`

You can extract the unknown `s1` (standard deviation of sample 1) with:

`sd1 = (ci_upper1 - mean1) / qt(.975, df = n1 - 1) * sqrt(n1)`